# Can not access system properties set in pom.xml for maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: java, maven, autotest, system-properties, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using maven-failsafe-plugin to run my auto-tests. I added system properties in pom.xml and need to use them in my code. But when trying to refer to them, I'm always getting 'null' instead of property values. I already looked faq http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/system-properties.html and tried to play it in different ways but still no success.

Here is a cut of my pom.xml with mentioned plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <parallel>methods</parallel>
               <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
               <systemPropertyVariables>
               <browser>MYSYSTEMPROPERTY</browser>
                  <!--Set properties passed in by the driverbinary downloader-->
                  <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                  <webdriver.ie.driver>${webdriver.ie.driver}</webdriver.ie.driver>
                  <webdriver.opera.driver>${webdriver.opera.driver}</webdriver.opera.driver>
               </systemPropertyVariables>
               <includes>
                  <include>**/*WD.java</include>
               </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>integration-test</goal>
                     <goal>verify</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

I.e i'm interested in fetching property ***browser*** property value (its supposed to return 'MYSYSTEMPROPERTY'). And here is how I refer to it in my code:

System.getProperty("browser".toUpperCase());

Comment: Why are you doing `System.getProperty("browser".toUpperCase())`. property names are case sensitive. use `System.getProperty("browser")`

Comment: Deendayal Garg, thanks a lot, this is solved the issue. My bad...it was supposed to be (System.getProperty("browser")).toUpperCase()); It works. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that i could help. Happy coding.